# Get arbitrary user entity with tokens

Tags: tokens

Is there a way to retrieve an arbitrary user entity via tokens inside a node field?

### For example:

Let's say I have a field name `Source`, which contains a reference to an external news publication.

I have a user on my site named "Jane Doe".

I want to be able to put something like this in the source field.  The example is a little fudged b/c I don't think Tokens has a "link" type token, but the question is more about getting data for an arbitrary user:

> New York Times, citing [user:link:Jane Doe].

And have that rendered as

> New York Times, citing [Jane Doe](http://example.com/staff/jane-doe).

### What I have tried

I've attempted this in the node body field (using the `token_filter` module).

I can get data for the current user with, such as with the token `[current-user:url]`.

But I haven't figured out how to get data for an arbitrary user.

I've tried:

- `[user:url:1]`
- `[user:url 1]`

Comment: Tokens work the other way round - they get _given_ a context to work with (node/user/taxonomy term/whatever), they don’t take part in loading/preparing that context. You might need to write a custom filter for this

Comment: This is right, core has two user tokens, `current-user` for the global context and `user` for the local user. The second one works locally in a user field, but not in a node field, because then the local entity is a node. So you would need to define a third type of user token in a custom module which gets the fields of an arbitrary user, which is no problem to be used globally then, because it doesn't depend on local data.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a token that, given a user ID, would return data about that user account. *current-user* returns data about the currently logged-in user, while *user* returns data about the user account passed to the function (in Drupal 7, or the method in Drupal 8) that replaces tokens with their values: [`token_replace()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21token.inc/function/token_replace/7.x).

It would be possible, for a module, to implement a token that returns data about every user accounts. With such a module, for example, *users:1:name* could return the username for the user account #1, while *users:2:name* would do the same for the user #2.